# Simple PHP Registration Form Only Collects NULL Values?

Tags: php, forms, post, input, authentication

I am attempting to create a basic login/registration for a website using PHP. The code below shows that I required config.php which I tested and it connects to my site smoothly.  What happens is when I go to the page, and enter in values, no matter what I enter for email and password, it says they always match. When I try to output the values of email1 and email2, it outputs nothing. I think the form isn't collecting the data when you press submit.  If anyone could see what I am doing wrong it would be so appreciated!

```
<?php
require('config.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $email1 = $POST['email1'];
    $email2 = $POST['email2'];
    $pass1 = $POST['pass1'];
    $pass2 = $POST['pass2'];

    if($email1 == $email2) 
    {
        echo "Emails match.<br />";
        if($pass1 == $pass2)
        {
            echo "Passwords match.<br />";
        }
        else 
        {
            echo "Sorry, your passwords do not match.<br />";
            exit();
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "Sorry, your emails do not match.<br /><br />";
    }

}
else {
$form = <<<EOT
<form action="register.php" method="POST">
First Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
Last Name: <input type = "text" name = "lname" /><br />
User Name: <input type = "text" name = "uname" /><br />
Email: <input type = "text" name = "email1" /><br />
Confirm Email: <input type = "text" name = "email2" /><br />
Password: <input type = "password" name = "pass1" /><br />
Confirm Password: <input type = "password" name = "pass2" /><br />
<input type = "submit" value = "Register" name = "submit" />
</form>

EOT;
echo $form;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've forgotten the underscores for all `$POST`'s

Change them all to `$_POST`

It's a [**superglobal**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) which 8 out of 9 of those require the underscore, unlike `$GLOBALS`

- $GLOBALS <=== No underscore required for this one.
- $_SERVER
- $_GET
- `$_POST` <=== Change them all to this.
- $_FILES
- $_COOKIE
- $_SESSION
- $_REQUEST
- $_ENV

---

Had [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) been set/on, you would have been signaled of the error, and multiple times:

> Notice: Undefined variable: POST in...

To enable it, you can add the following after your opening `<?php` tag:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

**N.B.:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

***Sidenote:***

Since you're *obviously* running the entire code from the same page, you can simply change `action="register.php"` to `action=""` if you want.

---

**Passwords**

I also noticed that you may be storing passwords in plain text. This is not recommended.

Use one of the following:

- [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471)
- [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)
- [`bcrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)
- [`scrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt)
- [**On OPENWALL**](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)
- [**PBKDF2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)
- [**PBKDF2 on PHP.net**](http://php.net/hash-pbkdf2)
- PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.
- Compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/

Other links:

- [**PBKDF2 For PHP**](https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm)

---

- If you use plain text as a password storage method, I'm afraid that it will just be a question of time before your site gets compromised.

Comment: I agree, all post variables must be catched with `$_POST` because `$POST['anyvalue']` is telling to PHP that you're using your own dynamic array (which is empty); and as additional advice **any** validation must be on client side not in server side

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. It fixed my problem.  I also haven't done anything with password encryption yet, so I will look into the functions you mentioned. Thanks again!

Comment: @ConnorFoley You're welcome Connor, glad to have been of help.